# How to rebuild all my Ruby gems?

Tags: ruby, rvm, rubygems

I ran into an apparently known issue with the native C compiler on OS X 10.8 not building Ruby gems correctly, so I installed GCC as suggested.

How do I have rvm rebuild all of the already-installed gems?

I tried `rvm update --rubygems 1.9.3`, which seems like it should work (at least, according to the documentation), but I get the rather cryptic error message:

```
ERROR: rvm update has been removed. See 'rvm get' and rvm 'rubygems' CLI API instead
```

I have no idea what this means, and I have not been able to figure out an incantation for `rvm` (with `get`, or any other command) that recompiles my gems.

Answer (score 19):

You can rebuild all your gems with:

```
gem pristine --all
```

Assuming there is no issue with your Ruby or Rubygems installation and only with the gems, you shouldn't need to use rvm at all. If however you need to upgrade your Rubygems, you can try this command to upgrade it to the latest version:

```
rvm rubygems latest
```